# Error 403 when I tried open page with spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new in Spring security. I need create 3 types of autontification.

```
by ip 
by sms 
by pin code
```

Now I tried realize auth by ip. I use spring security.

I get ip address of client(my spring-boot app) and pass to backend server(another remote java server) by rest. if user is authenticated I get this User in my spring app and I wand show him index.html or if not - I get null and I want show him login.html

I create `AuthenticationProvider`

```
@Component
public class IPAddressBasedAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Autowired
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Autowired
    AuthService authService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();
        AuthLkUser authLkUserByIp = authService.getAuthLkUserByIp(ipAddress);

        if (authLkUserByIp == null) return null;

        boolean b = authService.checkAuthLkUser(authLkUserByIp);
        if (b) return null;
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("John Principal", "PlaceholderPWE");
        result.setDetails(authentication.getDetails());
        result.setAuthenticated(true);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I open page for example index.html and my spring app in debbug mode  I check in debbug point(method is worcked) and i have my `authLkUserByIp`  (user is authenticated normaly). I have `result` and returne it. But on the page I have error

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Jul 11 12:48:25 ALMT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access is denied
```

But user is authenticated normaly. Why I have error?

I tried by [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786243/5620472)

But I do not have web.xml. All configs in code.

I have some quations:
1. Why I get error and how can fix it?
2. When I trid realize another two types authontification How can I manage it?

Answer (score 0):

i think you're missing the `grantedAuths`, because Spring security works with roles.

this is an example of how i handle authorization with a `CustomAuthenticationProvider`

```
@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = String.valueOf(auth.getName());
        String password = String.valueOf(auth.getCredentials().toString());

        Usuarios us = null;
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            us = user.findByName(username);
            success = passwordEncoder.matches(password, us.getClave());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }    
        if (success == true) {
            final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            String authority;
            switch (us.getRoles().getNombre()) {
                case "administrador":
                    authority = "ROLE_ADMIN";
                    break;
                case "vendedor":
                    authority = "ROLE_VENDEDOR";
                    break;
                default:
                    authority = "ROLE_NONE";
                    break;
            }
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority);
            grantedAuths.add(grantedAuthority);
            final UserDetails principal = new User(username, password, grantedAuths);
            final Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, password, grantedAuths);
            us = null;
            return authentication;
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Credentials");
        }
    }
```

First i check the user authority on my service, find it in my database, i think you can skip this, and assing directly your role with `GrantedAuthority`.

Then you can build your `UserDetails` and set the information of the user and his role with `GrantedAuthority`.

And finally build your `Authentication` to return it. with all the previus steps.